# Onsen App deploy to webserver

Tags: onsen-ui

I'm quite new to Onsen/Angular and just got my first app running. I run it locally with following command:

```
cordova run browser
```

To put it on the Webserver I did run the following commend

```
cordova build
```

Then uploaded and unzipped the generated "package.zip" to the webserver. But when accessing the page all angular code is not processed. I see the main page with lots of {{}}, see http://travelapp.slicks.com/

Am I missing an important step?

Many thanks and regards,
cucub

Answer (score 0):

Got it running using gulp following the instructions here: https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI
Somehow the package.zip build by cordova was not complete / kind of corrupt...